# Html Agility Pack - Parsing <li>

Tags: c#, .net, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I want to scrape a list of facts from simple website. Each one of the facts is enclosed in a `<li>` tag. How would I do this using Html Agility Pack? Is there a better approach?

The only things enclosed in `<li>` tags are the facts and nothing else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
List<string> facts = new List<string>();
foreach (HtmlNode li in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li")) {
    facts.Add(li.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: Note that SelectNodes returns *null* when "*... no node matched the XPath expression*".

Comment: If your LI tags aren't closed, the following bug may be relevant: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/29218