# C#, parsing HTML page, using HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Following this example, I can find the LI sections.

[Html Agility Pack - Parsing <li>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881425/html-agility-pack-parsing-li)

However, I only want the LI items that reside inside the div with an id of "res".

How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
List facts = new List();
foreach (HtmlNode li in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='res']/li")) {
    facts.Add(li.InnerText);
}
```

[XPath Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1095) might also help you with future XPath queries.

Comment: All correct, but may want to check HtmlNodeCollection for null in the event none exist.

Comment: Excellent!  And thanks for the XPatch Checker tip too.  I can definitely use that.