# How to get the value of <li> from a database field?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

In my application, I have TINYMCE as an html editor to accept this values:

- SpeedyCourse
- Zerix
- Optimum Innovatus
- Optimum Source

Once inserted, the field in my database looks something like this.

```
<ul>
<li>Speedy Course</li>
<li>Zerix</li>
<li>Optimum Innovatus</li>
<li>Optimum Source</li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to get the value of the the li tags when I access the data.

Is there a fast and easier way to do this? The only way I can think of is through looping the values one by one. I'm using MVC3 by the way.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There is the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881425/html-agility-pack-parsing-li)

Comment: The data came from the database and not on the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are using SQL or not but if so you can add these two CLR Items to the Database...

```
[SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None, IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true, Name = "RegExSplitIndex",
    SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.None, FillRowMethodName = "RegExSplitIndexRow",
    TableDefinition =
        "Match NVARCHAR(MAX), MatchIndex INT, MatchLength INT, NextMatchIndex INT"
    )]
 public static IEnumerable RegExSplitIndex(SqlString input, SqlString pattern, SqlInt32 options)
{
    if (input.IsNull || pattern.IsNull) return null;
    var matchcol = Regex.Matches(input.Value, pattern.Value, (RegexOptions)options.Value);


    var matches = matchcol.Cast<Match>().ToList().Select(MatchKeys.Translate).ToList();

    if (matches.Any() && matches.All(i => i.MatchIndex != 0))
    {
        var ix = matches.OrderBy(i => i.MatchIndex).First().MatchIndex;
        matches.Add(new MatchKeys() {MatchIndex = 0, MatchLength = 0, NextMatchIndex = ix});

    }

    return matches;
}

public static void RegExSplitIndexRow(Object input, ref SqlString match, ref SqlInt32 matchIndex, ref SqlInt32 matchLength, ref SqlInt32 nextMatchIndex)
{
    MatchKeys m = (MatchKeys)input;
    match = new SqlString(m.Match);
    matchIndex = m.MatchIndex;
    matchLength = m.MatchLength;
    nextMatchIndex = m.NextMatchIndex;
}
```

Then In your sql query you can use can use the Split Function like this to split out html tags:

```
OUTER APPLY [dbo].RegExSplitIndex(<YourdbField>),'(<(?:"[^"]*"[''"]*|''[^'']*''[''"]*|[^''">])+>)|\n',0) REM
```

And check to see what the the match value (`[REM].[Match] = '<li>'`)

you can use the match index and length to know where you need to start to get the actual value from the split string

if you don't have access to CLR then you can still use regex to split and do it all from within your code using a similar strategy